# $styles is undefined with webpack and typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, sass, webpack-style-loader

I have a typescript SharePoint spfx solution. When I compile using webpack my $styles become undefined but I am able to use the class names directly.

I feel like there is a configuration issue here, can someone help?

Here is my scss:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

//.alert.alert-warning.customalert {
//  text-align: center
//}

.app {
   .top {
        text-align:center;
        justify-content: center;
        .customalert {
          margin-bottom: 0px !important;
          font-size: 14px;
        }
      }
  }
```

Here is the div I am outputting:

```
import styles from './AppCustomizer.module.scss';
return `<div class="${styles.app}">
        <div class="${styles.top}">
          <div class="alert alert-${alertStatus} ${styles.customalert}">
            <strong>${alertTitle}</strong> ${alertDescription}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    and here is my webpack.config.js:

        const path = require("path");
    const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

    module.exports = {
      mode: "development",
      entry: ['@babel/polyfill',
        path.resolve(__dirname, './Classic/client/bootHeader.ts')],
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: "ts-loader",
            exclude: /node_modules/
          },
          {
            test: /\.(s*)css$/,
            use: [
              // fallback to style-loader in development
              process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
                ? "style-loader"
                : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              "css-loader",
              "sass-loader"
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "url-loader",
                options: {
                  limit: 15000, // Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings
                  name: "images/[hash]-[name].[ext]"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: "[name].css",
          chunkFilename: "[id].css"
        })
      ],
      resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
      },
      output: {
        filename: "classicBundleAG.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "Classic"),
        libraryTarget: "umd"
      },
      //externals: [
      //  "@microsoft/sp-loader",
      //]
    };
```

Note that if I access the styles directly like "customalert", then the style is recognized but $styles is never recognized and remains undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are expecting `object` from `styles`. Is it possible only with `css-modules`. To enable it add `modules: true` to your `css-loader` configuration:

```
          {
            test: /\.(s*)css$/,
            use: [
              // fallback to style-loader in development
              process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
                ? "style-loader"
                : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              {
               loader: "css-loader",
               options: {
                modules: true
               }
              },
              "sass-loader"
            ]
          },
```

Comment: Hi Nick, that was it! I actually found this solution earlier but discounted it because my custom styles stopped working completely. In fact they were working but I had an annoying caching issue that only corrected itself once I had made a change to my scss and rebuilt. Another thing I found is that I really did not like the long unqiue translated class names that webpack does by default with no hint of what the original name is. I prefer things like mystyle_xyz but I managed to get mystyle back by using this setting in the webpack config:localIdentName:'[local]'